# How to convert If statement to switch statement?

Tags: java

how can I convert this if statement to switch statement by considering that I am using two variables here and I tried to solve it but not working

```
int child;
char gender;
int temp;
child=console.nextInt();
gender=console.next().charat(0);
if(gender=='m' && children>=4)
  temp =1;
else if(gender=='m' && children<4)
  temp =2;
else if(gender=='f' && children<4)
  temp =3;
else
  temp=4;
}
```

this is my code

```
   int children;
    double temp;
    char gender;
    children=console.nextInt();
    switch(children , gender )
    {
      case < 4, 'm':

        temp=1;
      break;

      default : salary=600;
    }
```

Comment: `"i tried to solve it but not working"` -- where is your attempt? Always post this with your question, and tell us of any errors it is causing and misbehaviors.

Comment: `switch` doesn't support ranges `>=4`, so you're going to have a `if` statement somewhere in there

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235152/can-i-use-a-case-switch-statement-with-two-variables

Comment: You should leave this as it is. `switch` is not a good fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by having a look at [The switch Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

The switch statement is basically evaluating a single condition per case.  You can use drop through conditions, but that's a lot of additional code.

For example, something like...

```
switch (gender) {
    case 'm':
        temp = 0;
        if (children >= 4) {
            temp += 1;
        } else {
            temp += 2;
        }
        break;
    case 'f':
        temp = 2;
        if (children >= 4) {
            temp += 2;
        } else {
            temp += 1;
        }
        break;
}
```

would generate the same results as your `if` statements

If you preferred to use pure `switch` statements, you could do something like...

```
switch (gender) {
    case 'm':
        temp = 0;
        switch (children) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                temp += 2;
                break;  
            default:
                temp += 1;
        }
        break;
    case 'f':
        temp = 2;
        switch (children) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
                temp += 1;
                break;
            default:
                temp += 2;
        }
        break;
}
```

Java's switch statement doesn't support ranges :(

Comment: Your inner switches need `break` added.

Comment: @PaulBoddington That's funny, I'm sure that tested correctly, wonder what I was look at :P

Answer (score 1):

switch (gender) {

```
case 'm':
    temp = (children >= 4)? 1:2;
    break;
case 'f':
    temp = (children >= 4)? 4:3;
    break;
default:
    temp = 4;
    break;
```

}