# can google apps script switch more then one expression or better in if?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, switch-statement

In **google app script** can you have more than one **expression** in a **switch** or better in an if ?

```
switch (A_min,B_max) {
case A_min<0 and B_max<0
break;
case A_min>0 and B_max>0
break;
case A_min<0 and B_max>0
break;
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235152/can-i-use-a-case-switch-statement-with-two-variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a case/switch statement with two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235152/can-i-use-a-case-switch-statement-with-two-variables)