# multiple input match parameters to get 1 output?

Tags: javascript

Okay, I don't even know how to phrase this question, let me begin with small set.
Suppose, I have 3 input data fields:

```
let user= 'P' (Primary) or 'S' (secondary)
let key = k1 (random key)
let verification= passed or failed
```

Now the value of the key depends on the `user` and `verification`

```
if(user=='P' && verification === 'passed)
  return {k1:A}
if(user=='S' && verification === 'passed)
  return {k1:S}
if(user=='P' && verification === 'failed)
  return {k1:F}
```

Now, imagine possible number of values for user are 10, verification 3 and keys are 10. 
Then this code becomes ugly. Similarly, it would be if I choose Array.
This would be simple if I have to write server-side app with DB. Then I could simply fire the query. What would you think the best way to solve this for browser JS app?

Again, **just looking for ideas and not code. Thanks!**

Comment: How can you have three cases for verification? Is it not just passed or failed?

Comment: Did you consider using a switchcase with 2 variables, the way it's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9235189/13602909)

Comment: @JavaScript 3rd verification value - NotAttempted :)

Comment: @mahmoudayoub I think switch would reduce some if--else but may still need if-else to complete the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JavaScript:

- json object store
- access/query like an array

```js
const flagValues = {
    ssnValidation: {
        Primary: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        Secondary: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        AuthorizedUser: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        BusinessUser: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        Other: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
    },
    dobValidation: {
        Primary: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        Secondary: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        AuthorizedUser: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        BusinessUser: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
        Other: { Passed: 'P', Failed: 'F', NotAttempted: 'NA' },
    }
}

flagValues["ssnValidation"]["AuthorizedUser"]["Failed"]
```