# Use switch statement with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I want to use switch statement with 2 variables, for example, `a` and `b`, something like this:

```
switch(a,b){
  case(1,1): // a = 1 and b = 1
    doSomething()
    break
  case(1,2): // a = 1 and b = 2
    doSomethingElse()
    break
  case(0,2): // a = 0 and b = 2
    doOtherthings()
    break
  default
    doNothing()
}
```

I know this code doesn't work, so is there any alternative way to do this?

Comment: The whole point about `switch` is to allow you to switch between different possible cases of _one_ variable. You need to use something else like an `if...else` statement.

Comment: @Andy This is not as obvious as you're stating. The OP's case suggests pattern-matching-like behaviour of `switch`, which is how it works in, for example, Swift.

Comment: @Trung There must be `:` present after `default`, otherwise it's a `SyntaxError`

Comment: But we're not talking about Swift. The question is about JavaScript [and there's documentation on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). `switch` is a very bad use-case for this. @DimaParzhitsky

Comment: I understand and support all of that, the OP's question clearly lacks even minimal research effort. My point is that SO is a Q&A site, and some questions sometime stem from a confusion between the workings of different languages. But being condescending in these cases is rude, and we shouldn't discourage people from asking questions out of confusion.

Comment: FWIW this is possible in Swift (I know the question is about JS). https://www.swiftbysundell.com/tips/switching-on-multiple-values/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a case/switch statement with two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235152/can-i-use-a-case-switch-statement-with-two-variables)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `if` statements instead.

```
if (a === 1 && b === 1) doSomething();
else if (a === 1 && b === 2) doSomethingElse();
else if (a === 0 && b === 2) doOtherthings();
else doNothing();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible, you just need to translate your tuple into a unique, scalar case.

For example, while I don't advise it, you could rewrite your example as such:

```
switch(a+':'+b){
  case('1:1'): // a = 1 and b = 1
    doSomething()
    break
  case('1:2'): // a = 1 and b = 2
    doSomethingElse()
    break
  case('0:2'): // a = 0 and b = 2
    doOtherthings()
    break
  default
    doNothing()
}
```

You could even build your cases dynamically from other variables, if you so choose, if you wanted to obfuscate it even more. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer would be to use a `switch (true)`.

```js
switch(true){
  case a === 1 && b === 1: // a = 1 and b = 1
    doSomething();
    break;
  case a === 1 && b === 2: // a = 1 and b = 2
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
  case a === 0 && b === 2: // a = 0 and b = 2
    doOtherThings();
    break;
  default:
    doNothing();
}
```